# Python - Search and Autofil in treeview

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am doing Searching for data in treeview.

[image: treeview]

My expectation is only the result which I want is display in treeview. But it only appear on the top while all the rest are still there. The code is below :

```
def search(i):
    # grab what was typed
    global typed_var
    typed = po1_entry.get().lower()
    for eachitem in my_tree.get_children():
        if typed in str(my_tree.item(eachitem)['values'][0]):
            typed_var = my_tree.item(eachitem)['values']
            my_tree.delete(eachitem)
            my_tree.insert("", 0, values=typed_var)
```

Is there any solution to solve that ?

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?  The solutions are all very different.  And are you saying you want to clear out the entire treeview before adding the new items?

Comment: @TimRoberts its tkinter framework. What I want is only what I searching is appear in the treeview -> mean that only 1 row of seaching available in the treeview. The entire are clear out

Comment: That's certainly not what your code is doing.  All you're doing is deleting any row that contains your match.  You would need your `delete` line to be before your `if`, so you delete every line.

Comment: @TimRoberts it wont work. If I modify as yours the rest are still there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the principle is valid, this should work:

```
def search(i):
    # grab what was typed
    typed = po1_entry.get().lower()
    for eachitem in my_tree.get_children():
        search = my_tree.item(eachitem)['values']
        my_tree.delete(eachitem)
        if typed in search[0]:
            my_tree.insert("", 0, values=search)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to search for data in a `treeview` and display only the results that match the search query while removing the other rows. However, the code you provided seems to have a logic issue that causes only the matched item to be displayed at the top of the `treeview`.

The issue is in this line:

```
my_tree.insert("", 0, values=typed_var)
```

You are using `0` as the second argument, which specifies the index where the new item should be inserted. This means the new item will always be inserted at the top (position 0) of the `treeview`. Instead, you should insert it at the appropriate index based on the search results.

Here's an updated version of your `search` function that should work as expected:

```
def search(i):
    # grab what was typed
    global typed_var
    typed = po1_entry.get().lower()
    
    # Clear existing items from the treeview
    my_tree.delete(*my_tree.get_children())
    
    # Insert only the matching items back into the treeview
    for eachitem in original_data:  # Use your original data source here
        if typed in str(eachitem[0]):  # Assuming eachitem is a list of values
            my_tree.insert("", "end", values=eachitem)
```

Comment: Thank to your code it helps better. But there is one problem :